# Using Multithread for connect more than one connection string

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to implement multi thread for connection string which will retrieve more connection string from file it's working but it's taking so much time so I want to use multi thread. the following are code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.WithTPLAndParallelOptions();
        }               
        private  object threadLock = new object();
        public  void ConnectDBAndExecuteQueryWithLock(string connectionString)
        {
            lock (threadLock)
            {
                try
                {
                    string mysqlQuery = "SELECT PS_CD,COUNT(*) AS OFFLINE_FIR_COUNT FROM t_fir_registration WHERE state_cd=18 AND lang_cd=99 GROUP BY PS_CD";

                    //string connectionString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AUTODATA;Password=abc@123;User ID=sa";
                    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(mysqlQuery, connection))
                        {
                            command.CommandTimeout = 80;
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Console.WriteLine("Executed Thread.. " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }     
       public  void WithTPLAndParallelOptions()
        {
            string cctns_offline_DBConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cctns_offline_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"].ToString(), "*.properties",
                                          SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            int ThreadCount = filePaths.Length;
            ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
            options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5;
            //Create Parallel.For to execute the task
            Parallel.For(0, ThreadCount, options, i =>
            {

                foreach (string fileName in filePaths)
                {
                    // i = i + 1;
                    // Read a text file using StreamReader
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName))
                    {
                        String line;
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {

                            if (line.StartsWith("db.url"))
                            {
                                string[] PS_CD = fileName.Split(new[] { "\\", ".", "_" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                                string[] ip_address = line.Split(new[] { ";", "//", "/", ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                                if (ip_address[3].ToString() != string.Empty && ip_address[3] != "SQL2K8CLUSTER")
                                {
                                    string connstringrpl = cctns_offline_DBConnectionString.Replace("PS_IP", ip_address[3].ToString());
                                    ConnectDBAndExecuteQueryWithLock(connstringrpl);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Am not sure what your intention here is - you have a lock in your code - which means only one thread can execute the code below at a time - so unsure of what you are trying to do here. Also given this piece of code with locks - the possibility of deadlock could cause your code to slow down as well.

Comment: it wrong code for implementing thread.i try to multi thread for more than one connection string.

Comment: If you're doing IO then multi-threading will likely cause your code to go slower. Multi-threading is really only useful for CPU-bound operations.

Answer (score 1):

1) Currently your `Parallel.For` and `foreach` loops are nested, which means that each iteration of outer `Parallel.For` loop will execute all iterations of inner `foreach` loop all over again. So if you have for example 10 files, `ConnectDBAndExecuteQueryWithLock()` will be executed 10*10 = 100 times, which is probably not what you want, making your program much much slower. To fix this, remove `foreach` loop by replacing

```
foreach (string fileName in filePaths)
{
    ...
}
```

with

```
{
    var fileName = filePaths[i];
    ...
}
```

2) As pointed out by Jaya, `lock (threadLock)` causes that only one thread at a time can execute database query, making your multi threaded program virtually single threaded. Because your code inside `lock` doesn't use any shared variable, it is safe to remove the `lock` completely.